# How to show all details of the stored post while also hiding the query set

Tags: python, search

While I was adding a search bar in my blog. I had a design error I keep on getting query sets. Also when I search for the name of the post I want it show the name, snippet, author and others.(Example below with code.) Also Everything bold are meant to be a link.

What it shows:

```
<QuerySet [<Post: sports | Kaushik>]>
```

What I want:

```
**Sports** - **Sports** - **Kaushik Jay** - June 16, 2021 - (**Edit**) (**Delete**)
Click link Above to reach the blog
```

views.py:

```
def search_posts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        post = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=searched)


        return render(request, 'search_posts.html',{'searched':searched, 'post':post})

    else:

        return render(request, 'search_posts.html',{})
```

search_posts.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    
    {% if searched %}
        <h1>Search Results For {{ searched }}</h1>
        <br/>
        {% for posts in post %}
            {{ post }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
        <h1>Hey!! You Did Not Search For Anything.</h1>

    {% endif %}
    

    <br/><br/>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the list of posts as `post` and in your template you iterate as `for posts in post` but you display the `post`.

Comment: Sorry, do not understand what do you mean. I would like an answer that gives example and answers in a bit depth.

Comment: Using inconsistent names makes the explanation dificult. Typically looping over lists should look like this:
``for element in items`` but your template for loop is the other way around.

Just display the posts variable inside the for loop: ``{{ posts }}<br/>``

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you so much @Florin Ciurcanu. I probably got confused while I was using similar names Thanks. I will advise you to just write it as an answer so that this question has been answered.